# Existence of two different well-orders in infinite set such that the corresponding well-ordered sets are not isomorphic.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Prove that if there is a well-order $<_1$ in $A$, then there is a well-order $<_2$ in $A$ for which the corresponding well-ordered sets are not isomorphic.

I found the problem in exercise section. Initially I used the fact that every well-ordered set is ismorphic to an ordinal, but after that I got stuck because in no way could I verify the existence of second well-ordered set. For finite sets I know that all well-orders are isomorphic, but I have no idea what to do when the set is infinine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that for any infinite ordinal $\alpha$, $|\alpha|=|\alpha+1|$ (but of course $\alpha$ is not isomorphic to $\alpha+1$ as a well-ordered set).

To prove this, find a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ by applying the logic of "Hilbert's hotel": Map $0$ to $\alpha,$ then map $1$ to $0$, $2$ to $1,$ $3$ to $2,$ and so on. Then map everything $\ge \omega$ to itself.

Comment: Ok, that infinite ordinal α with its usual ordering will be isomorphic to a well-order <A,<1>, but what would be the well-order that is isomorphic to the ordinal α+1, I just cannot imagine how to construct it and what it looks like. Can you explain how you do it in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: @John $a<_2 b$ if and only if $f(g(a))< f(g(b))$ where $g$ is the order isomorphism from $(A,<_1)$ to $(\alpha, <)$ and $f$ is the bijection described above.

Comment: So, the idea is to see that there is a bjection between α and its successor and after that to conclude α and α + 1 are not isomorphic as well-ordered sets because α is proper initial segment of α + 1 and thus (α+1,<) is isomophic to a well-ordered set (A,<2) and thus concluding (A,<1) and (A,<2) are well-orders that are not isomorphic to each other in A. Am I correct or I am missing something again? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @John Yes, that sounds right

Comment: A perfect, simple answer (with a minimum of words -- that's good!).